# Number of times that throw a dice using distribution table

Tags: probability

**Suppose** that the dice throw experiment has Gaussian distribution. **Using the Gaussian distribution table**, how can I calculate the number of times that I need to throw a dice to get 6 with 0.99 of probability?

Comment: Normally we expect a single throw of a die to have a uniform distribution.  The Gaussian comes from the sum of many throws.

Comment: And most dice have discrete faces while a Gaussian random variable has a continuous distribution

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the chance that one roll is not a $6$?  What is the chance that every one of $n$ rolls is not a $6$?  What should the last be to have the chance of at least one $6$ be $0.99$?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the normal approximation to the binomial distribution. Let $X$ denote the number of $6$'s we get in $n$ tosses. If $X\sim \text{binom}(n,p)$ then $X\sim N(np, npq)$

Note that normal approximation works best when $p$ is close to $\frac{1}{2}$ and/or $n$ is large.

We wish for

$$P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{-\frac{n}{6}}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}}}\right)\geq0.99$$

Find the $n$ that satisfies this.

**Note:**

The binomial distribution would be more suitable.

We wish for

$$P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n\geq0.99$$

You must solve for $n$.

R statistical software gives that $n=26$ should do the trick.

```
> sum(dbinom(1:26,26,1/6))
[1] 0.9912645
```

Usually normal approximation only works when $np\gt 5$ but in our case $$np=26\cdot\frac{1}{6}\approx4.33<5$$